# Best way to implement rook moves and possible moves in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have board [8,8] and I'm trying to implement the horizontal movement and vertical movement based on the movements up, down, left and right, movements of a rook on a chessboard and I am having difficulty in how to move piece to square with the number of square to move.

```
(defun board ()
 '((64 35 74 26 21 57 12 28) 
   (43 15 47 53 24 56 42 29) 
   (51 41 71 31 17 45 55 30) 
   (67 66 22 T 54 75 32 38) 
   (13 11 16 23 25 27 33 20) 
   (34 36 37 44 46 52 61 48) 
   (10 49 59 69 68 70 50 40) 
   (62 63 65 72 73 76 77 58)))
```

The Rook moves horizontally and vertically any number of squares, forwards or backwards. In the diagram the Rook can move to any of the highlighted squares.

[image]

Function to check if the coordinates are valid

```
(defun position-valid (x y)
  (and (>= x 0) (>= y 0) (< x 8) (< y 8)))
```

Function that will move the tower according to the coordinates (x, y)

```
(defun move-piece (x y dx dy board)
  (let ((new-board (copy-tree board))
        (new-x (+ x dx))
        (new-y (+ y dy))
        (piece (nth x (nth y board))))
    (setf (nth x (nth y new-board)) nil
          (nth new-x (nth new-y new-board)) piece)
    new-board))
```

Function that moves the piece down

```
 (defun DOWN (x y board) 
   (cond
    ((equal (position-valid (+ x 1) (+ y 0)) 'T)
     (move-piece x y 1 0 board))
    (T NIL)))
```

Function that moves the piece to up

```
(defun UP (x y board) 
  (cond
    ((equal (position-valid (- x 1) (+ y 0)) 'T)
     (move-piece x y -1 0 board))
    (T NIL)))
```

Function that moves the piece to the left

```
(defun LEFT (x y board) 
  (cond
    ((equal (position-valid (+ x 0) (- y 1)) 'T)
     (move-piece x y 0 -1 board))
    (T NIL)))
```

Function that moves the piece to the right

```
(defun RIGHT (x y board) 
  (cond
    ((equal (position-valid (+ x 0) (+ y 1)) 'T)
     (move-piece x y 0 1 board))
   (T NIL)))
```

now the goal is to implement the vertical and horizontal movements based on the movements mentioned above so that the piece is moved and in this case, I think that we still need to implement the possible moves based on the type of movement and how many squares to move

I implemented this list of operators for horizontal and vertical movement but it is not working

Function that moves the Tower horizontally

```
(defun HORIZONTAL (x y n mov board) ;;n is number of square to move
  (cond
    ((and (equal (position-valid (+ x 0) (- y 1)) 'T) ;;left
          (equal (position-valid (+ x 0) (+ y 1)) 'T));;right     
          (cond
               ((equal mov 'LEFT)  (LEFT x y board))
               ((equal mov 'RIGHT) (RIGTH x y board))
               (T (HORIZONTAL x y (1- n) mov board))))
   (T NIL)))
```

Function that makes the Tower move in the vertical direction,

```
(defun VERTICAL(x y n mov board) ;;n is number of square to move
  (cond
    ((and (equal (position-valid (- x 1) (+ y 0)) 'T) ;;up
          (equal (position-valid (+ x 1) (+ y 0)) 'T));;down
          (cond
               ((equal mov 'DOWN)  (DOWN x y board))     
               ((equal mov 'UP)    (UP x y board))
               (T (VERTICAL x y (1- n) mov board))))
   (T NIL)))
```

and how to get the possible moves of the tower on the board based on the type of moves

Anny suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you are building too many functions which are unnecessary. What I would do is to have a MOVE function, based on move-piece, which would do both horizontal and vertical displacement. Since you have the parameter mov, which can be UP, DOWN, LEFT or RIGHT, the horizontal and vertical movements are already implicit, so there is no need to have a separate function for each direction.
So this is what I would do:

```
(setq board 
 '((64 35 74 26 21 57 12 28) 
   (43 15 47 53 24 56 42 29) 
   (51 41 71 31 17 45 55 30) 
   (67 66 22 T 54 75 32 38) 
   (13 11 16 23 25 27 33 20) 
   (34 36 37 44 46 52 61 48) 
   (10 49 59 69 68 70 50 40) 
   (62 63 65 72 73 76 77 58)))


(defun position-valid (x y)
  (and (>= x 0) (>= y 0) (< x 8) (< y 8)) )


(defun move-piece (x y dx dy board)
  (let ((new-board (copy-tree board))
        (new-x (+ x dx))
        (new-y (+ y dy))
        (piece (nth x (nth y board))) )
    (when (position-valid new-x new-y)
      (setf (nth x (nth y new-board)) nil
          (nth new-x (nth new-y new-board)) piece ))
    new-board))


(defun MOVE (x y n mov board) ;; n is number of squares to move
  (case mov
    (UP (move-piece x y 0 (- n) board))
    (DOWN (move-piece x y 0 n board))
    (LEFT (move-piece x y (- n) 0 board))
    (RIGHT (move-piece x y n 0 board))
    (otherwise NIL) ))
```

And then, if you want to get a list of all possible moves:

```
(defun valid-moves (x y board)
  (let (result)
    (dolist (mov '(up down left right) result)
      (dotimes (n 7)
        (when (move x y n mov board)
          (push (list n mov) result) )))))
```

Comment: thanks, sometimes to arrive at the solution, we have to create several functions although it is unnecessary but at least they will realize the objective, it´s working as expected

Comment: One does not quote symbols in CASE.

Comment: There is no ELSE in CASE. Use OTHERWISE instead.

Comment: True, fixed it. Thanks

Comment: the `valid-moves` it's working just in this initial position, and in the other position with empty square it's not working correct in this table https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6gTJ.png